# Segfault in ffmpeg when running from a shellscript executed in java

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, sh

I know there are some questions touching this subject, but none have helped me solve my issue.

### Purpose:

Transcoding a video taken,from a queue, from .mov to h.264 (for now only that)

### Solution:

Building a java application that gets the next in the queue, transcodes it then repeat

### Problem:

I made a script to execute ffmpeg correctly wich I run from java (using ProcessBuilder).

Script runs without a problem in console, but running with java nets a Seg fault in ffmpeg..

Code in java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./ffmpeg-convert.sh",folder + recID);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

in the script file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Running script with argument: $*;

./ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i $1.mov -vcodec libx264 -fpre /ffmpeg/ffpresets/libx264-slow.ffpreset $1.flv >/tmp/trace.txt 2>&1 </dev/null
```

and output in trace.txt:

```
FFmpeg version git-d23845f, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  9 2011 17:51:49 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil    50. 37. 0 / 50. 37. 0
  libavcore     0. 16. 1 /  0. 16. 1
  libavcodec   52.112. 0 / 52.112. 0
  libavformat  52. 98. 0 / 52. 98. 0
  libavdevice  52.  2. 3 / 52.  2. 3
  libavfilter   1. 75. 0 /  1. 75. 0
  libswscale    0. 12. 0 /  0. 12. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 40.00 (40/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/javarecorder/0896dd9e926a5852e5c7317ff5e91cd1446996dd.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
  Duration: 00:08:32.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7344 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: qtrle, rgb24, 1280x800, 6638 kb/s, 8.08 fps, 40 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
[buffer @ 0x432e050] w:1280 h:800 pixfmt:rgb24
[ffsink @ 0x4382740] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x4382a40] w:1280 h:800 fmt:rgb24 -> w:1280 h:800 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
[libx264 @ 0x4375590] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x4375590] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x4375590] 264 - core 114 r1900 60ef1f8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=200 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to '/var/www/javarecorder/0896dd9e926a5852e5c7317ff5e91cd1446996dd.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
    encoder         : Lavf52.98.0
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1280x800, q=0-69, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 40 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-09-26 19:32:24
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Hard to read all the cfg options set, but `--enable-postproc` and the tail-end of the output, 'Press [q] to stop encoding' seems to be a clue that ffmpeg is excepting user input that your java code can't provide. Good luck

Comment: It's only expecting input if I want to stop it, wich i dont. But the shellscript is running fin outside of java..

Comment: can you turn off the option on ffmpeg that is asking for user input, if nothing else, to eliminate my theory as a possibility (that is, if it still hangs, and you don't see the prompt, then my idea is not the correct solution). Good luck.

Comment: added "</dev/null" to the script still same

Comment: I'm out of ideas, except that you'll get more eyes on your problem if you change your shell tag to bash or ksh or ?? which ever shell you are really using. Good luck.

Comment: Are you reading the input stream of the created Process object? If you don't, then the internal buffer might get full, leading to a deadlock... But, I cannot think how it can segfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing was running java with "-Xms64m -Xmx64m". Aparently I had missed running the application with those :P